# Adding a column to a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to add a new column to a dataframe based on the value of a existing column using `pyspark`.

[image]

For example, if this is the original dataframe, I want to add a new column called "parent's data", which contains the data of the parent based on the column "parent_id", so that the resulting dataframe looks like below.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can use self join on id and parent_id to achieve your desired output.

Comment: What have you tried? This is just a simple join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there are multiple ways to achieve this . However, the simplest way is to create a new dataframe using 2 columns of existing dataframe. Then join the 2 dataframe to acieve this.

Here is the code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 2], [2, 'b', 3], [3, 'c', 1]], columns=["id", "data", "parent_id"])
print(df1)
sparkdf=spark.createDataFrame(df1)
sparkdf.show()
sparkdf2=sparkdf.select('id','data')
sparkdf2.show()
sparkdf.registerTempTable("sparkdf")
sparkdf2.registerTempTable("sparkdf2")

sparkdf3=spark.sql('select a.id,a.data,a.parent_id,b.data from sparkdf as a join sparkdf2 as b on a.parent_id=b.id')
sparkdf3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from your two columns, id and data, and then add your new column using `withColumn`:

```
>>> d = {row["id"]:row["data"] for row in df.collect()}
Out[260]: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

---

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit

m = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*d.items())])
df = df.withColumn('parent_data', m[df['parent_id']])
```

Which prints back:

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)

+---+----+---------+-----------+
|id |data|parent_id|parent_data|
+---+----+---------+-----------+
|1  |a   |2        |b          |
|2  |b   |3        |c          |
|3  |c   |1        |a          |
+---+----+---------+-----------+
```